# Override parameter of mocked service with PHPunit and Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am testing a simple addAction, the method from the service I am calling has a parameter which calls a method from the abstract controller. When i run the test mocking the method it breaks as it is running the $this->getUserId() method.

Here is the method I am testing:

```
    public function addAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('leaveRequestService')->addLeaveRequest($this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(), $this->getUserId());
        $returnValue = $this->redirect()->toRoute('leaverequest/list');
    } else {
        $users = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('userService')->findAllUsers();
        $returnValue = new ViewModel(array('users' => $users));
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Here is my test:

```
Public function testAddPostAction()
{
    $this->mockBjy();
    $this->mockZFC();

    $leaveRequest = $this->leaveRequestMock();
    $leaveRequestMock = $this->getMock('Employment\Service\LeaveRequest\leaveRequestService', array('addLeaveRequest'), array(), '', false);
    $leaveRequestMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('addLeaveRequest')
            ->with(array(),2)
            ->will($this->returnValue($leaveRequest));

    $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
    $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
    $serviceManager->setService('leaveRequestService', $leaveRequestMock);

    $this->dispatch('/leaverequest/add', 'POST', array('user' => '2', 'reasonforleave' => 'PHPunit', 'leaveRequestDates' => '05/06/2015 - 05/15/2015'));
    $this->assertModuleName('Employment');
    $this->assertControllerName('employment\controller\leaverequest');
    $this->assertControllerClass('LeaveRequestController');
    $this->assertActionName('add');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('leaverequest/add');
}
```

I am uncertain on how to override/skip/ignore the getUserId method. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks